# How to convert String "MM-DDTHH:mm" to DateTime in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

in my code i can get 2 types of string that represents dateTime:

1.`"2013-09-05T15:55"`

2.`"09-05T19:10"`

How do i convert it to a valid DateTime?

i tried the following code but it throws an exception for the second format:

```
String departureDateStr = "09-05T19:10";  
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(departureDateStr);
```

how do i convert the second type of string to a valid DateTime ?
do i need some kind of string manipulation?

thx,

Amir

Comment: What is the meaning of `09-05T19:10`? I mean could you convert it to day, month, year, hour, ...?

Answer (score 8):

[DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx) has an overload that allows you to pass multiple formats as an array. Each date string is then compared with the various formats within the array so you don't need to know ahead of time which format to look for.

```
string d1 = "2013-09-05T15:55";
string d2 = "09-05T19:10";

string[] formats = new string[] { "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm", "MM-ddTHH:mm" };
List<string> dates = new List<string>() { d1, d2 };

foreach (string date in dates)
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        //dt successfully parsed
    }
}
```

`TryParseExact` also returns false instead of throwing an exception if none of the formats in the array matched the input.

Comment: thx alot. by the way, is there a list of all supported formats ?

Comment: There's a list here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method with [custom datetime format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
string departureDateStr = "09-05T19:10";
string departureDateStr2 = "2013-09-05T19:10";

var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(departureDateStr, "MM-ddTHH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(departureDateStr2, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or universal call for both formats:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(departureDateStr, new[] { "MM-ddTHH:mm", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm" }, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DatetIme.ParseExact() method for this. It converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its `DateTime` equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

```
String departureDateStr = "09-05T19:10";
IFormatProvider provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "MM-ddTHH:mm";
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(departureDateStr, format, provider);
```

If you need this conversion a lot of times, then you can even make it an extension method as below:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
   public static DateTime ToDate(this string str)
   {
      IFormatProvider provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
      string format = "MM-ddTHH:mm";
      return DateTime.ParseExact(str, format, provider);
   }
}
```